# Can every $X \subseteq (0, 1)^2$ be covered by a countable union of closed disks satisfying these properties?

Tags: geometry, analysis

The properties are:

(1) The disks are all contained in $[0, 1]^2$.

(2) No two disks intersect in their interiors (but they are allowed to intersect at the boundary).

(3) The center of each disk is in X.

Comment: Take $X$ which is exactly the boundary of your square.

Comment: @bof I do mean disk, yes. I forgot that circles only include the outside. And I changed it from [0, 1] to (0, 1) to remove the trivial counterexample from Moishe that I thought of soon after posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter-examples abound even among nice subsets of the unit square. For instance, take $X$ to be the graph $y=x^2$ over the interval $(0,1)$. Then for any two closed disks with disjoint interiors, $D(p_i,r_i), i=1,2$ centered at points $p_i\in X$, we have
$$
\partial D(p_1,r_1)\cap \partial D(p_2,r_2)
$$
is either empty or is a point which is not in $X$.
(Use strict convexity of the function $f(x)=x^2$.)

From this, it follows that if $D(p_i,r_i), i\in {\mathbb N}$,  is a sequence of closed disks with disjoint interiors centered at points $p_i\in X$, then the arcs $A_i:=  D(p_i,r_i)\cap X$ are pairwise disjoint. Then the same argument as the one proving uncountability of Cantor sets, shows that the complement
$$
X\setminus \bigcup_{i\in {\mathbb N}} A_i
$$
is uncountable. Note that I am not even using the requirement that the disks are contained in the unit square.